# how can i save the data and variable in Pycharm workspace

Tags: variables, pycharm, rstudio, workspace

i was a R user, now i need to use python, how can i save the data and variable in the workspace just like the Rstudio as the second picture shows? so i can use the previous data and variable in my next project
[Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjLPp.jpg)
[Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVbjt.png)